# Getting "Error: couldn't get currently installed version for letsencrypt" when trying to renew my certificates

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt

I started getting an error when trying to renew my letsencrypt certificates on Ubuntu 15.04 + nginx server.

Even when I try running the `certbot-auto` command, I see the following:

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt:
An unexpected error occurred:
VersionConflict: (certbot 0.11.1 (/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('certbot==0.10.2'))
Please see the logfile 'certbot.log' for more details.
```

The `certbot.log` file provides the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 858, in main
    plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 183, in find_all
    plugin_ep = PluginEntryPoint(entry_point)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.plugin_cls = entry_point.load()
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2295, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
VersionConflict: (certbot 0.11.1 (/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('certbot==0.10.2'))
```

I also tried to run `sudo apt-get install certbot` and `sudo apt-get install certbot-auto`, and I get one more error: `E: Unable to locate package certbot`.

What could be the issue here, and what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The raised exception actually tells you what's wrong, you're calling a certbot version that's too recent compared to the expected one.

From the looks of it, this is a botched update of certbot which has internal conflicts, I'd suggest pulling the latest version from GitHub and relaunch `certbot-auto`.

If this doesn't work, clear certbot's virtualenv and let it install freshly.